# findViewById won't work in InputMethodService, what do i do?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an android keyboard, this code works fine so far

```
package keyboard.rob.com;

import...

public class xyz extends InputMethodService 
implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private LinearLayout mInputView;

    @Override public View onCreateInputView() {
        mInputView = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
        return mInputView;
    }

...
```

but later on when I'm trying to make

```
LinearLayout LinLayBg = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LL_total);
```

to populate it with buttons, it show

"*The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type zyz *"

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think you are trying to call the method `findViewById(int id);` from a non instance of a View .

Try :

```
mInputView.findViewById(R.id.LL_total);
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it this way:

```
View.findViewById(R.id.LL_total);
```